# How many 6-digit numbers contain exactly 4 different digits?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, number-systems, decimal-expansion

my solution is---->
 NUMBER can be 777210 this i denote by aaabcd
                ------   this can be done in ---> 10*1*1*9*8*7*[6!/3!]
                  {1 for a thrice}
 NUMBER can be 772210 this i denote by aabbcd
------  this can be done in ------------> 10*1*9*1*8*7*[6!/(2!*2!)]
           {1 for a and b }

and then multiply the answer by 0.9 to remove 0 case at unit place

but correct solution is 
C(10, 4)* [C(4, 2)* 6!/(2!)2 + C(4, 1)* 6!/3!] 
294840

Comment: Would you mind editing this a bit? It's very hard to parse what you've written

Comment: Which was the $a$ and which was the $b$?  Can we tell them apart?  Divide your second term by two to account for this discrepancy.  You counted $aabbcd$ with $a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4$ as a different outcome than $bbaacd$ with $a=2,b=1,c=3,d=4$.  Similarly, $c$ and $d$'s numbers could have been swapped, so divide by two again.  In the same manner your first term is incorrect as any of $b,c,d$ could have been swapped, so divide by $3!$.

Comment: The answer they give counts $6$-digit strings, does not treat $0$ as special.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: The linked question was posted 11 hours after this one.

Comment: @barakmanos  In order to mark a question as a duplicate, it must have an accepted or an upvoted answer.  The linked question has upvoted answers.  This one does not.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: OK, I wasn't aware of all this...

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is that before permutations in  [ ], you are mixing up combinations and permutations.

A double check of the book answer by a slightly different formula is:

[Choose triple/double]$\times$ [Choose the remaining]$\times$ [permute]

which for patterns $AAABCD$ and $AABBCD$ yields

$0.9[\binom{10}1\binom 93\cdot  \frac{6!}{3!} + \binom{10}2\binom 82\cdot\frac{6!}{2!2!}] = 294840$

Answer (score 0):

In your `aaabcd` case, you have a factor of $\frac{6!}{3!}$ which I think is meant to account for "how many ways are there to choose 3 digit positions to be `a`?"

However, this number should not be $\frac{6!}{3!}$ but instead $\binom 63=\frac{6!}{3!\cdot 3!}$.

If your intention was to make this the multinomial coefficient $\binom{6}{3,1,1,1}$, then that will lead to overcounting, because for example 737527 will be counted both as `abacda`, `acabda`, `aadabca`, and so forth.

Similarly your second term has $\frac{6!}{2!2!}$ which overcounts for the same reason. You want something like $\binom{6}{2,2,1,1}\cdot\frac12\cdot\frac12$ to account for overcounting with the two pairs and the two singletons swapped, respectively.

This gives you the wrong numerical results for an approach that otherwise looks valid.

Comment: i know the problem it in aaabcd--> 10*1*1*9*8*7

Comment: @sana: I don't know what exactly that arrow means, but $10\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 7$ is certainly the correct count of numbers of the form `aaabcd` where leading zeroes are allowed.

Comment: but m getting wrong answer by using this.
correct for selection is C(10, 4)*C(4, 1)